# Firebase assistant not showing in Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-assistant

I am trying to connect Firebase with my app and I was following all the steps in [this link.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html)

I have the latest Google Repo and android studio 2.2.3, but when I open the Tools drop down menu there is no Firebase option.

[image]

Any idea of what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) instead

Comment: @SimonSchnell . Thanks but I already started adding FireBase manually to my app but I would like to know why I am not getting the assistant option

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In the Android Studio, go to **File** -> **Settings**, click on **Plugins** and then enable all **Firebase** plugins.

This image below should help.

[image]

Comment: Why is this not in the Google documentation? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I found this under Android Studio >> Preferences in Studio 2.3.3

Answer (score 8):

First you need to sign in to your Google account by clicking on the icon in the upper right corner of android studio. Then the Firebase item will appear in the Tools menu.
[image]

Comment: This is now the correct answer in Android 2021.1.1 - but still not mentioned in the firebase docs! https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Answer (score 1):

In android studio 3.6.1 I used the long way but it worked as shown below:

1. Log in  to Android Studio 3.6.1 from the to right user icon
2. Log in to firebase console with the same account address
3. On the firebase console start a new project
4. In the center of the project overview page, click the Android icon (plat_android) to launch the setup workflow.

   5.Enter your app's package name in the Android package name field

[image: Enter your app's package name in the Android package name field]

6. Add the Firebase Android configuration file to your app by:
7. Click Download google-services.json to obtain your Firebase Android config file (google-services.json).
8. Move your config file into the module (app-level) directory of your app.
9. To enable Firebase products in your app, add the google-services plugin to your Gradle files.
10. In your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (build.gradle), add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin. Check that you have Google's Maven repository, as well.
    11

    `buildscript {

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
      }

    dependencies {
        // ...

    ```
    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
    ```

    }
    }

    allprojects {
      // ...

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
      }
    }`
    11

.In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

12. Add Firebase SDKs to your app
    To your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), add the dependencies for the Firebase products that you want to use in your app.

    ```
    dependencies {
    ```

    // ...

    // Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'

    // Add the dependencies for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
      // For example, to also use Firebase Authentication
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'

    // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure that you've added
      // Google's Maven repository to your root-level build.gradle file
    }
13. Sync your app to ensure that all dependencies have the necessary versions.
14. If you added Analytics, run your app to send verification to Firebase that you've successfully integrated Firebase. Otherwise, you can skip the verification step.
15. Your device logs will display the Firebase verification that initialization is complete. If you ran your app on an emulator that has network access, the Firebase console notifies you that your app connection is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3 , Go To Tools - > Android - > SDK Manager - > under that plugins in which search Firebase and there are three plugins click all then your android studio restart and can see Firebase Assistant there under tools ... Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio 3.4.1, Go to **Tools** -> **Firebase**

[image]