# Unable to find Tools > Firebase in Android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-assistant

As per developers guide-https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html, I have installed Google Repository in order to get Firebase option in android studio. It is installed successfully as shown in below image:

[image: Google Repository installed successfully]

But still i am not able to find Tools > Firebase option in my android studio 2.2.3. As shown in below image:

[image: Tools > Firebase not visible]

Any idea, what can be the problem?
Thank you for attention!

Comment: just make sure you have tick-marked the android support repository in SDK Tools, although its bydefault selected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase assistant not showing in Studio 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446140/firebase-assistant-not-showing-in-studio-2-2-3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to start plugins

In Android Studio, just go to File -> Settings, click on Plugins and then enable all Firebase plugins.

Then check it will work for you

Comment: I am getting Tools > Firebase option now after enabling all Firebase plugins. Thank you :)

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan great answer. I didn't even know that option existed. *blush*

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks ..glad to share knowledge :)

Answer (score 3):

Check if you got Firebase plugins installed too:

[image]

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64 bit and Android studio 2.2.3. I do not get any update yet for updating android studio version.

Comment: See http://tools.android.com/ or change your upgrade channel in AS' update settings

Comment: Also check for installed plugins. See updated answer

Answer (score 3):

File->Settings->Plugin->
 : Firebase App Indexing 
 : Firebase Services
 : Firebase Testing

Enable all three plugins then you can find it in Tools