# Firebase assistant not showing in Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

In my Android Studio 3.4.1 tool section most shortcuts are missing. At this time I want the firebase to work, there are two problems I'm facing

1. Firebase is not visible in the tool section
2. when opened using search, it throws an exception: Firebase Assistant Fails to Launch

Tried

1. Updated the Android Studio to latest
2. Disabled the firebase and restarted, and enable and restarted
3. Tried to add to Menu

Thanks in Advance, Cheers !

[image: Android Studio Version]
[image: Installed plugins and repositories]
[image: Tool Menu]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase assistant not showing in Studio 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446140/firebase-assistant-not-showing-in-studio-2-2-3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446140/firebase-assistant-not-showing-in-studio-2-2-3  Please refer the answer of this question.